# Problem with jquery blur() event on Div element

Tags: jquery, html, onblur

I have problem hiding certain popup wich are based on divs. when i click out side those divs they dont hid. Here is the sample code what i m doing..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#MainCanvas div").blur(function()
            {
                alert("blured");
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="MainCanvas" style="width: 400px; height: 350px; border: solid 1px black;">
       <div class="ui-widget-content" style=" vertical-align:middle; height:60px; border: solid 2px black; width:300px;">
            Drag me around
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 25):

If I remember correctly, only A, AREA, BUTTON, INPUT, LABEL, SELECT, TEXTAREA create focus/blur events. If you want to hide the popup by clicking outside it, you have to for example listen to click events on document and check if the event occured inside or outside the popup.

Sample code:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('#MainCanvas, #MainCanvas *'))return;
    $('#MainCanvas').hide();
});
```

Comment: Or you could use mouseout if you don't want your users to have to click.  If they're going to have to click somewhere, you might as well have a close button on the dialog and have them click that.

Comment: Thanks rafael.. I got the point..

Comment: @Jehanzebafridi don't forget to check the answer you accept as accepted (the icon under the number left of the answer)

Comment: Whilst this works, for a more comprehensive solution, particularly if your popup layer contains a number of nested elements, all of which might get the click event, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4629849/1371408

Answer (score 6):

for div blur focusout() will work

```
 $('#divCustomerGroup').focusout(function () {
            alert('yo');
        });
```

Comment: to the top! Simple and elegant.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `tabindex` attribute on `div` tag:

```
<div class="my_div" tabindex="3"></div>
```

and after that blur event will be working:

```
$('.my_div').blur(function(){ 
   //code ... 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done it by using the following code

```
<script>
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('._dpcontrol, ._dpcontrol *'))
            return;
        $('._dpcontrol').each(
                function (index, value) {
                    var retrivedtextbox = $(this).find('._dpitem')[0];
                    $(retrivedtextbox).fadeOut();
                });     
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best idea would be to handle the mousedown event and check the element that invoked the event.

Answer (score 0):

I borrowed a tip from multiple solutions to make something easy.  Basically when I focus something I want it to appear, but if I click out of it, I want it to hide again.  So, if I click on something INSIDE the div that appeared, my click then goes to see if it finds a parent called "DivHoldingcustomController". If so, do nothing.  If it does not (because I clicked somewhere else, so whateve I clicked on does not have this parent), then hide the custom controller.

```
    $(document).on("click", function (event) {
        var groupSelectorArea = $(event.target).closest(".DivHoldingCustomController").length == 1;
        if (!groupSelectorArea)
            $(".SomethingIWantToHide").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mouseleave` method and solution

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#MainCanvas div").mouseleave(function()
        {
            alert("mouseleave");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has  `.focusin()` and  `.focusout()` methods for binding to blur and focus events on elements that don't fire a native javascript blur event.
[jQuery focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)