# Hide div on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery function where when an element is clicked a hidden div shows.

```
$('.openHide').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.hiddenContent').toggle();
});
```

I need to modify it s that I could close this div if I click back not just on the first element. Possibly on Blur, but I am not sure how to indicate the element...

```
$('.hiddenContent').blur(function() {
    $('.hiddenContent').parent().children('.hiddenContent').hide();
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<span class="openHide">text here</span>
<div style="display:none" class="hiddenContent">
     hidden content here
</div>
```

Comment: please provide the html content you're playing with here so we can have an ideea what element you're trying to access . we can't gues

Comment: to use .blur() on non-form elements you should add attribute tabindex=0 on the element

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. On the click on the span the div should be toggled
2. On the body click the div should be hidden
3. On the click on the div, the event should not be propagated to the body
4. On the click on the span the event should not be propagated to the body

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {    
      $('.openHide').click(function(e) {
           $('.hiddenContent').toggle();
           e.stopPropagation();
      });

      $(document.body).click(function() {
           $('.hiddenContent').hide();
      });

      $('.hiddenContent').click(function(e) {
           e.stopPropagation();
      });
   });
   ```

Comment: Or you could use MouseOver and MouseOut ;-). It gives a nicer effect (especially combined with FadeIn and FadeOut).

Comment: Thanks. I posted a comment above. I need to close the div when clicked anywhere else but on it. is it possible?

Comment: Pfff... I'm having some problems with the upload of the HTML / Javascript code... but the javascript code should be enough to work with your example.

Comment: @Kees - Yeah, I was noticing that. It doesn't seem to want to format at all. Very weird. Stackoverflow bug?

Comment: @Kees Works great, thanks! I just thought of an exception where i may have multiple instances of these pairs on the site. I need to make sure that only One is open at a time. Off to my next headache! Thanks again.

Comment: @JasCav... I think it is a bug, but I haven't been around a lot here.

Comment: @Santa if you have any trouble, just post it here and I'll help :-). jQuery rules and makes development a lot easier.

Comment: But when many div needs the same behavior , it will not be easy to control all of this, or we need to add many function handler to the document.onclick manywhere.

Answer (score 4):

If `.hiddenContent` is a div you won't be able to use blur, that only works on text inputs. `mouseout` may be an alternative, and `$(this)` is what I think you are looking for in this case:

```
$('.hiddenContent').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

#### Hide on clicking elsewhere

If you want to hide the div when you click outside the element you must watch for clicks all over the body of the page:

```
$('body').click(function() {
    // Hide all hidden content
    $('.hiddenContent').hide();
});
```

And then provide and exception for when you are clicking on the actually hidden content itself, and when you want to open it:

```
$('.hiddenContent').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation() });

$('.openHide').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next('.hiddenContent').toggle();
    // this stops the event from then being caught by the body click binding
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. It closed hiddenContent but only if I hovered over the area before rolling out. Is there a way to do a click away from the content area to close it?

Comment: @santa I have modified my answer in include a solution to do that.

Comment: Thanks. i tried but it does not even let my div to stay open. It opens and closes right away... :(

Comment: @santa you need to do the `stopPropagation()` stuff in your original click binding, I have modified that last block of code in my answer to correct this.

Comment: Not sure why, but it still closes my div when I click on it. Can it be due to the fact that my class for that div has  position:absolute; zIndex:5; ?

Comment: @santa Ah I think you need to stop propagation both when you open the thing and when you are clicking on it, however it seems like it should have worked anyway. Give my updated answer a try and let me know.