# jQuery blur() not listening to $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Followed by the HTML DOM:

```
<div class="opt">
    Options
    <div class="panel">
        <h3>i am in panel!!</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i click on the `.opt` it would show the `.panel` content, but then i need to trigger another event to hide the `.panel` when clicking outside of the `.opt` element. 
jQuery:

```
$('.opt').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('.panel').fadeIn();
    $this.blur(function(){
        $this.find('.panel').fadeOut();
        alert('i am from blur');
    });
});
```

Here is a demo [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hasantg/y0wsfpvb/)

But the `blur()` method is not executing, what i am doing wrong here technically?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985292/problem-with-jquery-blur-event-on-div-element. I tried your code with a tab index attribute and it works.

Comment: Look this:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985292/problem-with-jquery-blur-event-on-div-element][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985292/problem-with-jquery-blur-event-on-div-element

Comment: I noticed that it works with `mouseleave` instead of blur but then, it doesnt listen for clicks

Comment: Also, if you fire the event via jquery it responds fine. It also works fine in Internet explorer so might be a browser thing related to how is this event interpreted. The tab index trick seems to work tho.

Comment: It's almost always wrong to define one event handler inside another event handler. Every time you click on `.opt` it will add another `blur` handler to it, so you'll get multiple alerts.

Comment: @Barmar Okay, got it. but i'm using chrome and there was no alert at all!

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to use `blur` on a DIV. It's for input elements, that can receive and lose focus.

Comment: Okay, now i understand.

Comment: How about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element which shows how to detect clicks outside an element.

Comment: @Barmar Yes. Though the tabindex things do the job but i think i'm gonna follow that.

Answer (score 5):

You can try a click event on body instead of blur. Take a look at
https://jsfiddle.net/y0wsfpvb/7/

```
$('.opt').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('.panel').fadeIn();
});


$('body').click(function (e){ 
    if( $(e.target).closest(".opt").length > 0 == false) {
        $('.panel').fadeOut();
        alert('fake blur');
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont understand what the if{..} to do when clicking on the body.. can please describe?

Comment: If the target is .opt, I don't want to close the panel, so I return false to exit the event. The click event is on body, but if the inner element is inside a .opt, I return false to exit the method to keep the panel opened.

Comment: Okay, i think it would be better instead of stopPropagation() on the .opt .. what do you think?

Comment: Yes. With stopPropagation() you will not be able to detect another possible events on bubbling. For example an event on a parent div will not work.

Answer (score 2):

This works if you define de tabindex property for the div...
Try:

**HTML**

```
<div class="opt" tabindex="3">
    Options
    <div class="panel">
        <h3>i am in panel!!</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.opt').click(function(){

    $(this).find('.panel').fadeIn();
    $(this).blur(function(){
        $(this).find('.panel').fadeOut();
        alert('i am from blur');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the fade out action to the body's on click handler, and then add:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

to your opt class click handler to achieve this.

[Here is an example on codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/OyLPPd)